# how can I set the working directory in old version of docker in the run command?

Tags: meteor, docker

I am a bit new to docker and I have been trying to run deploy a meteor container with my meteor application. I have been using the dockerfile and instructions from https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/golden/meteor-dev/

However, I cant run `docker run -p 3000:3000 -t -i -v /path/to/meteor/app:/opt/application -w /opt/application meteor-dev` because my docker (version 0.5.3) does not recognize the flag (-w) to set the working directory.

Is there some workaround to set the working directory with docker 0.5.3? The work directory is already set in the [docker file](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/golden/meteor-dev/dockerfile), but I guess I need to set it again when I run the container.

Comment: By Docker standards, 0.5.3 is really old. Try to upgrade to the latest version (1.0.0 as of today).

Answer (score 0):

well, my workaround was to create a bash script that would go to the working directory and call the commands one by one. I created the bash script where my source is located  "/path/to/meteor/app" and call `docker run -p 3000:3000 -t -i -v /path/to/meteor/app:/opt/application meteor-dev bash /opt/application/start.sh` with the bash as command and my script as argument